# How I should fix if else statement didn't work

Tags: php

I want to test if user enter incorrect file number and ic, the message "Inccorect ref no and ic no" will shown, but it didn't work like that. It always shown the message "Thanks you for register attendance with us." Help me please..I'm new.

```
<?php
require "init.php";
    $file_number = $_POST["file_number"];
    $ic_no = $_POST["ic_no"];
    $attendance = $_POST["attendance"];
//$ic_no = $_REQUEST['ic_no'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO reg_attend(file_number,ic_no,attendance) SELECT reg_meeting.file_number,reg_staff.ic_no,'".$attendance."' FROM reg_meeting,reg_staff WHERE (reg_meeting.file_number = '".$file_number."' AND reg_staff.ic_no = '".$ic_no."')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$response = array();

if($result)
    {
        //var_dump($result);
        $code = "reg_success";
        $message = "Thanks you for register attendance with us.";
        array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
        echo json_encode($response);

    }
else
    {

        $code = "reg_failed";
        $message = "Incorrect REF No. and IC No.";
        array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
        echo json_encode($response);;
    }
mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

Comment: `if($result)` - this will always be true, unless your query runs into an actual error. If the SELECT portion of this statement simply returns no data, that is _not_ an error. Please go research how to properly determine if an INSERT statement created new records or not.

Comment: @misorude what i want to do,user need to input  file_number,ic, and  attend/absent..it will save in table reg_attend..file_number in reg_meeting.. ic in reg_staff already in table.. user must input correctly file_number and ic same with what in the table reg_meeting and table reg_staff.. the problem is,if user incorrectly either file number or ic,the message say "Incorrectly input" will shown..but in my case,the else statement not working very well..its still proceed with the message in if statement,but the data not save into db..

Comment: _“its still proceed with the message in if statement”_ - and I just _explained_ to you, why this happens. But instead of taking that into account, your response seems to be a mere repetition of what we already know - why? My advice that you please go and _research_ how to do this properly (determine if/how many rows an INSERT statement actually created), still stands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate your incoming data *before* you insert into your DB. It looks like currently, you will be inserting empty values into your `reg_attend` table. As this is likely successful, you will not be reaching the `else`.

If you need to validate that the passed in data exists, do a select first e.g.

```
SELECT reg_meeting.file_number,reg_staff.ic_no,'".$attendance."' FROM reg_meeting,reg_staff WHERE (reg_meeting.file_number = '".$file_number."' AND reg_staff.ic_no = '".$ic_no."')"
```

then check the results of that, before inserting.

As a side note, please please DO NOT use this code as shown. You should prefer to use query parameters with either PDO or mysqli. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: They are using INSERT … SELECT, so a record will only be inserted, if that SELECT statement returned any data. That _is_ the check for whether a matching record exists, “built in” into the statement already. The problem is that they are interpreting the return value of mysqli_query in a wrong way.